# Adding PubSub as a dependency causes errors with Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-pubsub

I am fairly new to Android and the Google cloud. I have written a test app which successfully writes to a firestore database. 
I wanted to extend my application by adding a feature to publish to a pubsub topic.
I added the following dependency line to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:0.33.0-beta'
```

Before I even added any new pubsub code, my app builds, runs, and immediately crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.tliv.mytestapp, PID: 27506
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeux.run(Unknown Source:23)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Provider io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.zzq(Unknown Source:84)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.zzdcr(Unknown Source:26)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.<clinit>(Unknown Source:12)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.zzdcs(Unknown Source:0)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmv.zzud(Unknown Source:0)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeti.<init>(Unknown Source:22)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source:74)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenh.run(Unknown Source:8)
                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw
                  at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:2469)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.zzq(Unknown Source:2)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.zzdcr(Unknown Source:26) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.<clinit>(Unknown Source:12) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmw.zzdcs(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmv.zzud(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeti.<init>(Unknown Source:22) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source:74) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenh.run(Unknown Source:8) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this. As soon as I remove the pubsub dependency, my code builds and runs fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries), "Google Cloud Java client libraries do not currently support Android".

You may want to use the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/pubsub/v1) instead for your project.

Comment: Wow, i totally missed that note about Android. Thank you!